# WPF radio button and text box - event handling

Tags: wpf, events

On what event should I add a handler for textbox to set radiobutton in front of it as checked when user clicks on textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx).

Comment: I'm trying this one tb.GotFocus += new EventHandler(Control1_GotFocus); but it doesn't work, I created a method void Control1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)... but the error is "No overload for 'Control1_GotFocus' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler"

Comment: @Sergey: How about `new RoutedEventHandler(Control1_GotFocus)`?